# How to springboot custom configuration file path?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Since my project has multiple environments and multiple small project groups, I need to handle the corresponding business logic according to different property names, but I can't find any parameter in bootstrap.yml that can set the custom configuration file path.

[image]

After I googled, I only found a way to modify the path of the custom configuration file through the startup class

[image]

Is there any other better way for me to configure it? Please help me!

Comment: `@ConditionalOnProperty`? or did I miss something?

Comment: @Eugene I have three different configuration options and I need to specify which configuration file to load according to spring.profiles.active when I start maven

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot look for your externalized configuration file in four predetermined
locations :

- in classpath root,
- in the package /config in classpath,
- in the current directory
- in /config subdirectory of the current directory.

  i think you want to load configuration file from /config folder.

You can programmatically tell Spring Boot to load your configuration files from
custom location as below :

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name:application,conf",
                        "spring.config.location:classpath:/your/location/of/config/folder,classpath:/another/location/of/congig/folder")
                .build().run(args);
```